# How a robot navigation algorithm can be evaluate?

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have implemented a potential field algorithm for robot navigation? How can I test this technique. Is there any best way to evaluate this algorithm?

What I am doing now is that I have set an environment having obstacles in gazebo. And when a goal is given to the robot, it reaches at goal position avoiding all obstacles. But when I am repeating same experiment with same environment, robot has some different trajectory every time.

Thanks

After 2 days
I have run some experiments in stage simulator. Again robot have not same trajectory every time. I have three scenarios here.

1. Run a robot without any obstacle.
   Without obstacles robot have same trajectory every time I repeat the experiment. It shows robot movement is very accurate.
2. Run a robot with 1 obstacle in the way to the goal.
   Every time robot has same trajectory, but there was a little difference. Or we can say trajectory was 95% same.
3. Run 2 robots, moving in opposite direction. On repeating this experiment every time I have some different trajectories.

Please Can anyone tell me that, Why it has this kind of behavior? Is there any noise in sensor data of stage simulator? I am running all my nodes in a launch file. I am considering that all my nodes start working at the same time. This could be effecting my experiments.

Thanks

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/38267/how-a-robot-navigation-algorithm-can-be-evaluate?/) by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on ROS Answers with karma: 81 on 2012-07-09

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo simulation often is not 100% deterministic as minor timing variations of the real-time dynamics simulation leads to small (sometimes also large :) ) jitter. We get pretty consistent results when simulating/evaluating path-planning/SLAM and other high level software however. Sounds like your potential field implementation might not be robust against such jitter with the parameters you used. Have you tried it with another simulator or real robot?

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2012-07-09

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-07-09**:
Thanks, Yes my potential field implementation is not so robust. And I have not tried it with any other simulator or real robot. But I think that I will try it in simulator stage. What do you think that how can I make my algorithm robust?

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-07-09**:
For an answer, this could be a separate question (with lots of additional information about what you are doing).

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2012-07-09**:
OK, Please can you suggest me some basic techniques of testing navigation algorithms. Or Is there any general rules to test robot navigation? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For testing and evaluating robot navigation

I was able to evaluate navigation algorithm using 4 testing parameters.

(1) total time (in seconds) to complete navigation task

(2) path length (in meters)

(3) curvature change

(4) Lateral stress.

I got help from an article
"Performance evaluation of pure-motion tasks for mobile robots with respect to world models"
by Daniele Calisi and Daniele Nardi

---

Originally posted by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) with karma: 81 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gavran](https://answers.ros.org/users/26097/gavran/) on 2016-09-30**:
hi, @abdullah, could you say how did you measure path length traveled by each robot? (there is an option as described [here](http://answers.ros.org/question/66671/traveled-distance-measurement/), but is there some better way for stage simulations?

**Comment by [abdullah](https://answers.ros.org/users/1083/abdullah/) on 2016-10-30**:
hi, I had used the same method that you have mentioned.